# Form is not posting while inserting maths equation in ckeditor

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, ckeditor, formula-editor

I have created a from with 5-6 textareas every one having ckeditor and while we insert equation through editor. It works fine @ local but i have got empty post array while using on server.

So any one know about any server permission that might be missing.

For information i am using ckeditor with latex equation editor plugin

here is my equation

> 81^{1/4}\times9^{3/2}\times27^{-4/3} (3^{4})^{1/4}\times (3^{2})3/2
>   \times (3^{3})^{-4/3}  \because  81=3^{4}, 9=3^{2}, 27=3^{3}
>   = (3)^{4\times 1/4 }\times (3)^{2\times3/2} \times (3)^{3\times-4/3}\because (a^{m}){n}=a^{mn}
>   =3^{1}\times 3^{3} \times 3^{-4}
>   = 3^{1+3-4}  \because a^{m}.a^{n}.a^{p} = a(m+n+p)
>   = 3^(1+3-4)
>   = 3^{0} = 1 \because a^{0}=1

While i am trying this equation my $post is empty, although if i remove  2or 3 "=" sign it works. I really struck with what happens there

I am working from last two days and done almost every thing i got on web

Please help me

Comment: Check sending data in browser (e.g. firebug)

Comment: as mentioned, check the POST request in dev tools of your browser

Comment: Thanks For your reply i have check and got my $post array as empty. It worked now after removing <p> tag from editor that is auto added from editor. . .So don't know what is the problem But is is solved by removing <p> tag.